# Are all iphone songs DRM protected while on the phone? AVAssetExportSession cannot find audio

Tags: iphone, ios, drm, avassetexportsession

When a song gets placed into itunes and then synced to iphone does it automatically put DRM on it?

I'm trying to copy an mp3 I wrote into a unity3d game on the iphone and play it and use it to make a video of the game.

This fails:
I wrote a song it does not have DRM. I dropped it into itunes and sync up the phone.
 I then use an iphone plugin for unity3d that copies it from from the iphone music library to a directory in the game. I can then play the song and create a video of the game with the song. Playing the song works fine.  But when I try to access the data using AVAssetExportSession to create the video it cannot find the audio tracks of the mp3.

This succeeds:
But if I paste the song directly into the game directory by dragging it from itunes into the game library it has no problem with the song or finding the audio tracks and creating the video.

Can anyone explain why this is failing. Is it a DRM issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title directly: No, all songs are not automagically DRM protected while on the iPhone.

That being said, you do need to jump through a few hoops if you want to get the song data, and AVAssetExportSession is a good way to do that.

The problem you are having really doesn't sound like a DRM issue.   It sounds like a path/URL problem for the audio file.    Some example code would help to better answer the other parts of your question.